# What would cause SSD to become not detectable?

Tags: boot, hardware, ssd

I recently purchased an Intel 520 120GB SSD and installed Ubuntu on it. Occasionally my system will freeze and I will have to ALT-PRINT SCREEN-REISUB to reboot.

Sometimes it will reboot and work just fine. Other times it just hangs at a flashing prompt. If I boot from a Live USB I can run Boot-Repair and it will usually reboot fine the next go round. I have noticed today that when I am running the live USB and open Nautilus my SSD partitions will sporadically disappear and reappear. Even if they are mounted.

I was thinking it was a poor connection, but I have tried a different SATA cable and a different SATA port. Is it possible I have a faulty SSD, or is there something different you have to do with SSDs to make sure they stay mounted (I was thinking like it has some sort of goofy power savings feature that needs to be disabled).

- I found the place in the bios where the SATA ports are listed. They are all set to AHCI(Chipset - SATA Mode = AHCI)
- The unmounting/remounting happens all the time. I think this is the relevant part of the syslog: http://pastebin.com/WxHdRAAq

Comment: What is the BIOS setting for that SATA port? ATA or AHCI or auto or something else? I've had problems in the past when it was set to ATA or auto.

Comment: In your BIOS somewhere (hit Delete or F1 or F10 on boot, it should say which button to "Enter Setup") it should list all of the SATA ports and what is connected to each of them, but where this screen is varies depending on your motherboard. It doesn't really matter which SATA port the SSD is connected to. For most people it's SATA0 or 1, and a DVD drive is the other one.

Comment: I found the place in the bios where the SATA ports are listed. They are all set to AHCI(Chipset - SATA Mode = AHCI)

Comment: Cool, sounds like something else then. Do you know the last time the umounting/remounting thing happened? Or does it happen all the time? You'll need to look at the system logs to hopefully find something related. If you do a `tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog`, can you post it on pastebin.com and link to it here?

Comment: The unmounting/remounting happens all the time. I think this is the relevant part of the syslog: http://pastebin.com/WxHdRAAq

Comment: That looks like a hardware issue - I'd get in touch with Intel directly. They may want you to do some BIOS and drive firmware updates, but I'd suspect the drive will be RMA'd and you'll be sent a new one.

Comment: I will vote for faulty SSD. I had one - it used to work fime for 1.5 years. One day it froze while my was working, and was not found by BIOS on next reboot. It worked after second reboot, though.... A  mouth later it stopped for second time and never worked again. It was replaced. Back UP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my empirical studies of numerous forum posts on SSDs/Linux, this is almost certainly a faulty SSD. Get it RMA'd. There is an off-chance it may be the controller (southbridge) BUT the likelihood is near-zero unless you have one of the botched Intel Cougar Point (Z68) chipsets with the SATA bug.

Comment: It was indeed a faulty SSD. I had it RMA'd and haven't had a single issue since I swapped it out.